# RXJava operate on exiting List instead of creating new

Tags: java, rx-java

I'm dipping my toes in to RXJava for the first time. The function below works just fine but I can't help thinking it can be improved. For instance I'm sure that I'm unnecessarily creating a new `List<Dish> sortedDishes` when I could be performing operations on the exiting `List<Dish> dishes` that is passed in, I just don't know how yet.

```
public void sortDishes(int categoryId, List<Dish> dishes) {
    final List<Dish> sortedDishes = new ArrayList<>();
    final Integer[] subCategories = dbInteractor.getSubCategories(categoryId);
    final ArrayList<Integer> cats = new ArrayList<>();
    cats.add(categoryId);
    if (subCategories != null) {
        cats.addAll(Arrays.asList(subCategories));
    }

    Observable.from(dishes)
            .filter(new Func1<Dish, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(Dish dish) {
                    Integer[] categories = categoryHelper.getCategorys(dish.getCategories());
                    for (Integer category : categories) {
                        if (cats.contains(category)) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<Dish>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Dish dish) {
                    sortedDishes.add(dish);
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Code Review. I hope you receive great answers!

Answer (score 2):

You're just abusing the library here. What you're doing can be done significantly more succinctly in standard java API:

```
public void sortDishes(int categoryId, List<Dish> dishes) {
    final Set<Integer> categories = new HashSet<Integer>();
    categories.add(categoryId);
    final Integer[] subCategories = dbInteractor.getSubCategories(categoryId);
    if (subCategories != null) {
        categories.addAll(Arrays.asList(subCategories));
    }

    final List<Dish> sortedDishes = dishes.stream()
        .filter(d -> categoryHelper.getCategories(d.getCategories())
                         .stream().anyMatch(categories::contains))
        .sort()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Note that this corrects a typo in `getCategorys`.

---

#### Further notes

Your dbInteractor's API could use a rework. I generally advocate against returning `null` from APIs that return a collection of elements, whether that's an Array or an actual Collection subclass.

I strongly suggest you consider returning `new Integer[0]` or even `Collections.emptyList()` because this will greatly simplify calling code by guaranteeing you're not returning `null`.

I also don't understand why the method is typed `void`. Either you actually modify the List you've received or you return a new List.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @Vogel612. I should say that I'm doing this on Android and as such don't have access to Streams. My bad for not tagging the question properly. I take on board your advice for returning empty collections instead of null, it is good thanks. The method I posted here was edited to remove some code which was not relevant to the question and operated on the resulting Observable. I included the lines at the top of the method to help describe what data I was operating on . The original question was about RXJava so I wasn't concerned with the rest making sense. Again, thanks.